# How to use Javascript rand function while building a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to turn this thing in JQuery and i cannot find how to use the rand function. I tried several ways but nothing worked. Please help!!!!

```
  function myBox() {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        el.style.width = rand(30) + 70 + "px";
        el.style.height = rand(30) + 70 + "px";
        el.style.borderRadius = rand(50) + "%";
        el.style.position = "relative";
        el.style.top = rand(150) + "px";
        el.style.left = rand(50) + "px";
        console.log(el);
        gameArea.appendChild(el);
    }


function rand(num) {
    //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor
        let tempVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
        return tempVal;
    }
```

Comment: What isn’t working?

Comment: So far nothing in this question seems to be related to jQuery.

Comment: *"nothing worked"* is not a good problem description. Add  the HTML and CSS with which you have the problem, preferably as a runnable snippet (use the toolbar). Explain what you expected from that snippet.

Comment: Is this function called when a button is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the actual element

```
const el = document.createElement("div");
```

```js
const gameArea = document.getElementById("game");

function myBox() {
  const el = document.createElement("div");
  el.style.backgroundColor = ["red","blue","green","yellow","pink"][rand(5)];
  el.style.width = rand(30) + 70 + "px";
  el.style.height = rand(30) + 70 + "px";
  el.style.borderRadius = rand(50) + "%";
  el.style.position = "relative";
  el.style.top = rand(150) + "px";
  el.style.left = rand(50) + "px";
  // console.log(el);
  gameArea.appendChild(el);
}


function rand(num) {
  let tempVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
  return tempVal;
}
myBox();
myBox();
myBox();
```

```html
<div id="game"></div>
```